# Python : How can I access Lotus Notes 8.5 Inbox to read emails

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, jira, lotus-domino

I want to make an script in python that reads mails from Lotus Notes 8.5 and then create for each email an issue in jira but it returns me this error when I try to read the mails from Lotus:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "from_Lotus_TO_Jira.py", line 46, in <module>
main()
File "from_Lotus_TO_Jira.py", line 39, in main
folder = notesDatabase.GetView('$Inbox')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\29131520-2EED-1069-BF5D-00
DD011186B7x0x1x2.py", line 1849, in GetView
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743866, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((8, 1),),pName

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'NotesDatabase',
u'Database  server_name!!C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Lotus\\Notes\\Data\\ma
il202\\myname.nsf has not been opened yet', None, 0, -2147217441), None)
```

here is my .py file

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes
import getpass

def main():
    # Get credentials
    mailServer = 'server_name' 
    mailPath = 'C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\mail202\myname.nsf'


    mailPassword = ''
    # Connect
    notesSession = win32com.client.Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')



    notesSession.Initialize(mailPassword)
    notesDatabase = notesSession.GetDatabase(mailServer, mailPath)

    # Get a list of folders
    folder = notesDatabase.GetView('$Inbox')
    document = folder.GetFirstDocument()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It can be done, but acessing it through IMAP(S) would be much-much easier. Just get your groupware admin to open up IMAP on the Domino server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308538

> The full filepath (e.g. "C:\notes\data\r_apps\haha.nsf") may
>   optionally be used when accessing local databases on a workstation. If
>   you specify a server name, however, or if the code is running on a
>   server, you must use the path relative to the Notes data directory
>   ("r_apps\haha.nsf").

I suggest either (a) not specifying a server or (b) only giving a relative path, ie `mailPath = r'mail202\myname.nsf'`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Notes COM classes. There is a nice shortcut call for opening the current user's mail database.  The [NotesSession class](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html?lang=en) contains a [GetDbDirectory method](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDBDIRECTORY_METHOD.html?lang=en), which returns a NotesDbDirectory object, and the [NotesDbDirectory class](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS.html) contains an [OpenMailDatabase method](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAILDATABASE_METHOD_DBDIRECTORY_COM.html).

I'm not a Python guy so I can't vouch for the exact syntax, but it should be along the lines of this:

```
notesSession.Initialize(mailPassword)
notesDbDirectory = notesSession.GetDbDirectory('')
notesDatabase = NotesDbDirectory.GetMailDatabase()
```

Note that the argument to GetDbDirectory can be an empty string or the name of a Domino server. It should not make any difference, as the GetMailDatabase method follows the same procedure as the [NotesDatabase.OpenMail method](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENMAIL_METHOD.html) (which is not exposed via the COM interface, therefore it is unavailable to Python). I.e., it looks at the current user's Notes client configuration to locate either a server-based or local replica of the user's mail database.

Also note that if this code is intended to run on one machine but process mail for many users on one Domino server, then you can't use the GetMailDatabase method. In that case, using the relative path as in @Hugh-Bothwell's answer would be correct, although I would strongly recommend adding some defensive programming via a call to [notesDatabase.IsOpen()](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ISOPEN_PROPERTY.html) in between the calls to the `GetDatabase()` and `GetView()`.

Comment: Hi again! There is a method in win32.com for Lotus  to move a email from an folder to an other folder ?

Comment: Comment threads really should not be used to ask a new question. Why not? Because StackOverflow is a community site and value to the community is improved that way. When other people are searching for an answer to the same question, they are much more likely to find it if the search result page comes up as "How do I move Lotus Notes messages to a different folder using COM from Python?" than if the result page comes up as "Python : How can I access Lotus Notes 8.5 Inbox to read emails".