# python win32com Lotus Notes Dispatch error

Tags: python, lotus, win32com, dispatch

I'm trying to use python to access Lotus Notes using the win32com module

```
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch
notesSession = Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

If I try a different application, eg. 'Excel.Application', I don't get the error.

Is there anything additional I need to make Lotus Notes accessible to python?

Thanks
Toby

Comment: Did you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659861/python-how-can-i-access-lotus-notes-8-5-inbox-to-read-emails

Comment: Yes, but my problem lies with accessing the 'Lotus.NotesSession' class at all. I'm suspecting the version of Notes used is here is non-standard in some way rendering the access via the standard COM classes unobtainable.

Comment: Notes has only standard versions, as far as I know. You could try to reinstall it, hoping that all libraries will be put in the correct place.

Comment: Is your Python 32 bits? As far as I know you cannot access the Notes COM server from a 64-bit Python interpreter.

Comment: @richieadler Thank you. After changing python to 32bit, the script works.